# Where did u,v,w coordinates originate?

Tags: coordinate-systems

Was it merely because x,y,z were already taken?   Although, w, was already used [Edit: I think].

Not meant flippantly, nor is this intended as a math trivia question.

And, secondarily, u,v are commonly used in UV Mapping, but I'm wondering if these three are bread and butter for subject areas such as differential geometry?

Comment: where did $x,y,z$ originate? No other letters were taken that time.

Comment: thanks for the prompt comment, but, hmm, I was asking about u,v,w not x,y,z ... did you mean u,v,w perhaps?

Comment: No,  I was asking about $x,y,z$ only. The reason is because the origin of $x,y,z$may have been before the origin of $u,v,w$. Furthermore,during translation, rotation , scaling and other invariant transformations of the coordinate space, we use a different coordinate system (or basis) to denote the new coordinates, along with transformations to and fro. The new coordinate system was normally represented with the letters $u,v,w$. This is still a tradition today in many books, and I think goes back to Descartes' days.

Comment: interesting ... back to Descartes? Wonder if some old google scans can show that. Makes sense it'd be that old.